# Push pubsub messages on app engine results in 403 error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to integrate google pubsub into my project. 
So far I managed to get everyhting to work (create/delete topics/subscriptions publish and pull messages) except for push endpoints, I am unable to sent messages to them.

I am using app engine flex environment, and used this code as sample: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java/tree/master/appengine-push

I am not getting any useful logs except a 403 error similar to this "
`POST /_ah/push-handlers/receive_message? HTTP/1.1" 403 156 - "-" "versionId-dot-projectId.com`"

I followed the document in here which explains what to do in case of 403, but no luck.

```
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/advanced#gae-endpoints
```

My questions:

- Does pubsub need ssl certificates even on app engine.
- If it does, what sort of self signed certificates are acceptable.

Comment: found anything?